# SQL Separate Table Keys from Group_Concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying to separate the IDPosts column as a single row for each ID (attempting to create a favorite post list).  The column next to it has all of the proper columns listed but are grouped, I want to obtain a row for each one grouped together in the favuserposts column.  See my picture and query below.  Please let me know if you need more information.

[image]

Displays everything but cannot display multiple favorite post IDs:

```
SELECT Users.IDUser, 
       Users.username, 
       Users.profile_picture, 
       Favorites.IDPosts,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT coalesce(Favorites.IDPosts,'')) as "favuserposts", 
       ( Select body 
         from Posts 
         where Favorites.IDPosts=Posts.IDPosts 
          AND Users.IDUser=Favorites.IDUser)    
FROM Users
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Favorites ON Favorites.IDUser = Users.IDUser
GROUP BY Users.IDUser HAVING COUNT(IDPosts)>0;
```

Comment: I wouldn't store multiple ids in one field. you can make a table which stores iduser and idpost.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid just that.  I have a favorites table that does what you just described with the post Id and user ID only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You group by IDUser. So all other fields you select are aggregates in some way. Either you specify the aggregate you want (MIN, MAX, GROUP_CONCAT, etc.) or you get a random match. So let's look at what you select:

- `Users.username` = a "random" username for the user id, but as there is just one name per userid of course, you get the one user name for the id
- `Users.profile_picture` = same as username; you get the one picture for the user
- `Favorites.IDPosts` = a random one of the user's post IDs
- `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT coalesce(Favorites.IDPosts,''))` = string of all distinct IDs
- `( Select body from Posts ...)` = a random one of the user's post bodies

So if you want a string listing all bodies, then use group_concat, just as you do with the post IDs:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
( Select body 
  from Posts 
  where Favorites.IDPosts=Posts.IDPosts 
  AND Users.IDUser=Favorites.IDUser
)) as bodies
```

Comment: Close but I do not want to group anything.  I want a separate row for each post.

Comment: @user2793987: Well, if you don't want to group by anything, then simply join all the tables and show the columns.

Comment: Figured it out by adding another foreign key.